# Evaluate $\frac{x^2}{y}$ where $x=a^{a^{a}}$ and $y=a^{a^{2a}}$

Tags: power-towers

Evaluate $\frac{x^2}{y}$ where $x=a^{a^{a}}$ and $y=a^{a^{2a}}$

> 1.$1$
>
> 2.$x^{a^{a}}$
>
> 3.$x^{1-a^a}$
>
> 4.$x^{2-a^a}$

**My solution**:

$x^2=a^{a^{a}}*a^{a^{a}}=a^{2a^{a}}$

$\frac{x^2}{y}=\frac{a^{2a^{a}}}{a^{a^{2a}}}=a^{2a^a-a^{2a}}=x^{2-a^a}$

I don't know where I am mistaked but our teacher gave the answer $1$. Could you please tell my mistake.

Comment: I think your mistake came from the fact that $(a^{a^{a}})^2 = a^{a^{2a}}$.

Comment: I don't see any mistake.  Looks correct to me.

Comment: @John But: $(a^{a^{a}})^2=a^{a^{a}}*a^{a^{a}}=a^{2a^{a}}$

Comment: @TahaAkbari, sry, my mistake. You were right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  As written in a comment to a previously deleted answer, $(r^s)^t=r^{st}$.  In this case, $r=a,s=a^a,$ and $t=2$.  So $x^2=a^{2a^a}$, not $a^{a^{2a}}$.  And using this rule again in reverse to add in a step you did not include in your solution

$$a^{2a^a-a^{2a}}=a^{a^a(2-a^a)}=(a^{a^a})^{2-a^a}=x^{2-a^a}$$

Comment: Are you sure?Because I asked from my classmate and he gave the answer 1 too.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Assuming $a^{a^a}$ means $a^{(a^a)}$ and not $(a^a)^a$, yes.

Comment: @TahaAkbari  The main problem is to understand who are the basis and the exponent. In my opinion Mike gives you the right answer, because if the basis was $a^a$ the brackets are needed.

Comment: @Mike of course.